# SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync method not immediately speaking

Tags: c#, .net, text-to-speech

I am trying to use the SpeakAsync() method to speak some text.  However, it doesn't start speaking anything until I call Speak().  I don't want to call Speak().  If I remove the Speak() method from this code nothing gets called at all:

```
        using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
        {

            synth.SelectVoice("ScanSoft Emily_Dri20_22kHz");

            synth.Rate = 10;
            synth.Volume = 100;

            synth.SpeakAsync("oh, i'm a lumberjack and i'm okay!  I sleep all night and I work all day!");
            synth.SpeakAsync("If he was dying he wouldn't bother writing ah!  He'd just say it!");
            synth.Speak("i don't want to go on the cart.");
            synth.SpeakAsync("We don't have a lord.  We're an anarcho-syndicalist commune.");
            synth.SpeakAsync("If you do not show us the grail, we shall take your castle by force!");
            synth.Speak("what do you mean, an african swallow or a european swallow?");
```

UPDATE:

It appears other people are having this problem but no solution has been found yet:

[other people having this problem](http://microsoft.public.windows.developer.winfx.general.narkive.com/q2pzb89K/speechsynthesizer-speakasync-stopped-working)

Comment: Is this a console app?

Comment: Yes.  It is a console app.  I copy-pasted some sample code from MSDN and then tried to expand upon it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `Speak` is a blocking call which keeps the program running. Since you're running this as a console application add `Console.ReadKey();` at the end of your code to ensure that the application remains running until the user presses a key.

Otherwise, the main thread will exit because `SpeakAsync` returns immediately so your program is flying through all those lines and then exiting which is why you don't hear anything.

Update based on comments -

The `using` block is disposing the `SpeechSynthesizer` almost immediately which is why nothing can be heard. You can either place `Console.ReadKey();` just before the closing brace of the `using` block or remove the `using` block and dispose of it manually later on.

Comment: I do have that.  I actually have a lot more code after these lines.  I only included the relevant snippet.  Even when I step through the debugger none of the SpeakAsync() calls do anything until a Speak() call is made.  Then all of the previous text gets spoken in addition to the text presented to the Speak() method.

Comment: Your async code is within a `using` block so the `SpeechSynthesizer` is being disposed almost immediately. Either remove the `using` block and handle the disposing manually or put the `Console.ReadKey()` just before your `using` block is closed.

Comment: You know, that seems to have worked.  I tried removing it last night and it didn't seem to do anything different.  I don't know why it is working now.  Maybe I was just tired.  If you post a new answer I'll accept it.

Comment: This worked for me and a simple way to dispose of the `SpeechSynthesizer` is to handle its `SpeakCompleted` event and dispose of `SpeechSynthesizer` in there instead of with a `using` statement.